# Xcode Error: “EXC_BAD_ACCESS”

Tags: c++, c, xcode, macos, file

I am attempting to compile and run a test C program in Xcode. This program reads 5 symbols from a text file and closes it. The program builds successfully, but when I try to run the program I get the error: GDB: Program received signal: "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" around fclose(in).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>

int main (int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    bool b;
    char inpath[PATH_MAX];
    printf("Enter input file path :\r\n");
    std::cin >> inpath;
    FILE *in = fopen(inpath, "r+w");
    char buf[5];
    fread(&buf,sizeof(buf),5,in);
    printf(buf);
    fclose(in);
    return 0;
}
```

What could be a cause of this?

Comment: Does the printf output appear OK?

Comment: Learning to use the debugger is part of the learning process of C or C++.

Comment: printf outputs more than 5 symbols for some reason...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah!  `sizeof(buf)` will return 5, so you're asking for 25 bytes in a 5-byte buffer.  This overwrites auto storage and clobbers `in`.

And, of course, note that `fprint(buf)` will be attempting to print a buffer with no terminating null, so it will print garbage beyond the end of what was read.

Comment: Thank you, `I edited to char buf[6]; fread(&buf,sizeof(buf),1,in); buf[5]='\0'; printf(buf); and it worked!`

Comment: @JakeBadlands -- I've never understood why `fread` was defined the way it is.  The double length parms are confusing and unnecessary and lead to many errors.

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
fread(&buf,sizeof(buf),5,in);
```

is wrong: read carefully the [man page of fread](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl3_fread.htm) (and remember that `sizeof(buf)` would be the size of the whole `buf` array).

The line

```
 printf(buf);
```

is wrong. Behavior is undefined if for instance `buf` would contain `%d`

You definitely should learn to use the debugger (and enable all warnings with your compiler).

Answer (score 2):

```
fread(&buf,sizeof(buf),5,in);
```

this says that you want to read the `buf` 5 times, which is not correct.

The second and third parameters tell `fread` the size of each element you want to read and the number of elements.